# Vertical scroll over FlexSlider 2 (responsive) initializes a horizontal slide swipe

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, flexslider

Not sure I've worded it just right, but when I touch scroll over the flexslider, if my finger isn't perfectly moving in a straight vertical line, the scroll stops and the flexslider begins to scroll horizontally.

Anyone experience this or have a fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue too, but only on iOS Devices, Android worked fine.
For me, turning off CSS-Transitions did it.

While initializing your flexslider set you can set use of CSS-transitions to false like this:

```
<script>
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        useCSS: false
    });
</script>
```

Further information: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/ -> Tab "Advanced"